Is there a per-episode list of major historical changes in For All Mankind?
The Wikipedia page for the AppleTV show For All Mankind covers the original Point of Departure of the series.

Sergei Korolev was the father of the Soviet space program; in our reality, he died during an operation in Moscow (in 1966) ... And after that point, their Moon program really never pulled together.... Our point of divergence was that Korolev lives, ... and he made their Moon landing happen.

Is there any list anywhere of other global history changes on an episode-by-episode basis (so I can avoid spoilers past where I am).
So I'm thinking of things like the early end of the Vietnam war in 1970.

Not a episode list, but there are a few good guides.... 1st: https://for-all-mankind.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline For a rougher one by season there are a couple screen rant pages. 2nd: https://screenrant.com/for-all-mankind-alternate-history-differences/ 3rd: https://screenrant.com/for-all-mankind-timeline-alternate-real-history-comparison/ I am sure there are many more, I found these by google searching: "timeline of for all mankind" and "For All Mankind changes from history"

@NJohnny I'd found some of those before. Though the fandom one I missed. The low quality of the screen rant is one reason I came asking. Skipping the Ted Kennedy change and Vietnam from just the first three episodes made it seem they weren't going to hit the points I was looking for.

Looking again though I can see some of the problem is the ordering within the Screen rant articles. I stop reading as soon as it references stuff I haven't seen, but coming back I can see some of the later points refer back to the earliest episodes.
